# Program doesn't edit output file

Tags: c, file, file-io, text-files, comments

I've created a program for my homework that takes as command-line arguments the names of 2 .c files and makes the second one a copy of the first without comments(at least that is what it should do)...

The program checks if it's inside a const char[] initialization if it is it skips forward until it's out of it, it checks to see if it can find an inline or a multiline comment.

If it finds an inline comment it skips to the following line.

If it finds a multiline comment it skips until after it.

In both cases, after skipping over the comment it checks to see if it's in a string and if it isn't it checks to see if a new comment starts.

When it isn't in a comment it puts every char in the destination file.

The problem is that the output file is always empty.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Invert(x) ((x) ? 0 : 1)

FILE *source, *destination;
int ch, nextch;
unsigned int isInString = 0;

void checkString(void)
{
    if(ch == '"')
        isInString=Invert(isInString);
}

void comment(void)
{
    if ((ch == '/') && (nextch == '/'))
    {
        while(ch == '\n')
        {
            ch=nextch;
            nextch=getc(source);
        }
        ch=nextch;
        nextch=fgetc(source);
        checkString();
        if(!isInString)
            comment();
    }
    else if ((ch == '/') && (nextch == '*')){
        {
            while (!((ch == '*') && (nextch == '/'))) {
                ch = nextch;
                nextch = fgetc (source);
            }
            ch = fgetc (source);
            nextch=fgetc (source);
            checkString();
            if(!isInString)
                comment();
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf ("error");
        exit(1);
    }
    source = fopen (argv[1], "r");
    destination = fopen (argv[2], "w");
    if (source == NULL )
    {
        printf("error");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (destination == NULL)
    {
        printf("error");
        exit(1);
    }
    nextch = fgetc (source);
    while (nextch != EOF)
    {
        checkString();
        if(!isInString)
            comment();
        putc(ch, destination);
        ch=nextch;
        nextch=getc(source);
    }
    fclose (source);
    fclose (destination);
    return 0;
}
```

The input file I'm using for testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define Invert(x) ((x) ? 0 : 1) //Macro pentru a schimba valoarea de adevar

const char test[]="/*Voi testa programul pe acest fisier*/ //Sper ca totul este ok!"; //Citeste continutul
/* variabile declarate global pentru a evita apelurile cu multi parametri */
FILE *fisieroriginal, *fisierprocesat;
int ch, nextch;
unsigned int string = 0;

void verString(void)//verifica daca ne aflam intr-un sir de caractere
{
    if(ch == '"')
        string=Invert(string);
}

void com(void)//elimina comentarile
{
    if ((ch == '/') && (nextch == '/'))//Verifica comenatariu linie
    {
        while(ch == '\n')//pana la sfarsitul liniei
        {
            ch=nextch;//aruncam caracterul
            nextch=getc(fisieroriginal);
        }
        ch=nextch;//aruncam caraterul /n
        nextch=fgetc(fisieroriginal);
        verString();//verifica daca incepe un sir de caractere
        if(!string)//daca nu,verifica daca incepe un nou comenatriu
            com();
    }
    else if ((ch == '/') && (nextch == '*')){//verificam pentru comentariu multilinie
        {
            while (!((ch == '*') && (nextch == '/'))) {//pana la sfarsitul comentariului
                ch = nextch;//aruncam caracterul
                nextch = fgetc (fisieroriginal);
            }
            ch = fgetc (fisieroriginal);//aruncam caracterul *
            nextch=fgetc (fisieroriginal);// si caracterul /
            verString();//procedam ca la sfarsitul ramuri de adevar
            if(!string)
                com();
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*
      Program ce primeste ca argumente pe linia de comanda doua fisiere .c si il transforma pe al doilea intr-o
      copie a primului dar fara comentari.
     */
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf ("Nu au fost specificate denumirile fisierului sursa si/sau fisierul destinatie!");
        exit(1);
    }
    fisieroriginal = fopen (argv[1], "r");
    fisierprocesat = fopen (argv[2], "w");
    if (fisieroriginal == NULL )
    {
        printf("Eroarea la deschiderea fisierului sursa");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (fisierprocesat == NULL)
    {
        printf("Eroarea la deschiderea fisierului destinatie");
        exit(1);
    }
    nextch = fgetc (fisieroriginal);
    while (nextch != EOF)
    {
        verString();
        if(!string)
            com();
        putc(ch,fisierprocesat);
        ch=nextch;
        nextch=getc(fisieroriginal);
    }
    fclose (fisieroriginal);
    fclose (fisierprocesat);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you attach the input file you use for testing?

Comment: I'm new, how do I attach a file?

Comment: This is mostly tangential to your current problem.  Note that if a line contains `//` and ends with a backslash (and newline), then the comment is continued onto the next line (because line-splicing occurs before comments are removed).  You probably don't have to worry about that.  Even more esoterically, the `/` and `*` of a start comment symbol can be separated by an arbitrarily long sequence of backslash-newline characters — and so can the `*` and `/` at the end of a comment.  Again, you probably don't have to worry about that at the moment.

Comment: You 'attach' a file by embedding its contents in the question as code.

Comment: Your code doesn't handle improper files correctly; you don't detect EOF in the middle of a comment.  That probably isn't your problem either — you're probably working with well-formed code.  Also (nit-picking details), `abc/**/def` is seen as two tokens, `abc` and `def`.  In effect, the comment is replaced by a space.  You should not create `abcdef` in the output.  Eventually, you'll need to deal with strings such as `"values (\"%s\" /* given name */, \"%s\" /* family name */, \"%s\" /* occupation */)\""`, which contains no C comments.  Comment handling is surprisingly tricky!

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf ("error");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`  When the error is about the command line parameter count, Typically a USAGE statement is used, similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s firstParam secondParam thirdParam\n", argv[0] );`

Comment: regarding: `source = fopen (argv[1], "r");
    destination = fopen (argv[2], "w");
    if (source == NULL )
    {
        printf("error");`  when the error is from a C library function, then should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest: `perror( "fopen of source file failed" );`   And this has to be immediately after the statement that indicated the error as the second call to `fopen()` changes `errno`

Comment: In your function `comment()`, while processing `//` comments, you have `while(ch == '\n')`; you need `while (ch != '\n')` (or, more carefully, `while (ch != EOF && ch != '\n')`).

Comment: Also, the first character output is a null byte if the file starts with a `/*` comment — that's not good (`diff` on a Mac says the file is a binary file).

Comment: I added the input file I'm using for testing. I understand my approach to comments and errors is trivial but I still can't figure why I don't get output.

Answer (score 0):

the only statement that is outputting character(s) to the `destination` file is in `main()`

```
putc(ch, destination);
```

However, the `recursive` function:

```
void comment(void)
```

will 'recurse' until EOF

so, at best, a EOF will be written to the `destination` file..

Therefore, the program logic needs to be redesigned

Suggest limiting the `comment()` function to only handle a single comment rather than the whole file.

Perhaps add functions:

```
isSlashSlashComment()
findEndSlashSlashComment()
isSlashStarComment()
findEndShashStarComment()
```

and add a 'state' of `inComment` that has the same precedence as a 'state' of `inString` so will not try to handle a string when in a comment and vice-versa.